Passing a prop up to a sibling in a layout page in React & React Router DOM
I am using React Router DOM 6.22 and React 18.2. I have the following router configuration:
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: (
      <>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <MainLayout />
      </>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <Dashboard title='Dashboard' />
      }
    ]
  }
]);

And my MainLayout.jsx file looks like this:
export default function MainLayout() {
  return (
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
  );
}

What I'm trying to do is get that title prop on the <Dashboard /> component up into my <Header /> component so I can add the title to my header. I am not sure the best way to do this without overcomplicating it or overthinking it. My initial thought is to use useState() or useContext() but I feel like there's an easier way.

I would suggest to use the context, because the title will change according to the url, for each different URL you need to update the title in the Header
